# Switch SSLVerifyClient within ReverseProxy context

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, client-certificates

This is a part of an Apache virtualhost configuration, the incoming request, which matches, are forwarded to the Apache Tomcat server. All clients must send a client certificate for authentication for App1, but for App2 it should be optional.

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /app1/services/App01 ajp://localhost:8307/app1/services/App01
ProxyPass /app1/services/App02 ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02

<Location /app1/services/App01>
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02
</Location>

<Location /app2/services/App02>
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02
</Location>
```

So is there a posibility to switch for app2 the SSLVerifyClient directive from required to optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading a lot of documentation and trying out different approaches I found the solution!

Bring all proxy directives into the Location context, set the **SSLVerifyClient** directive for these host or virtualhost to **optional** and put **SSLVerifyClient require** into the Location directive where it's needed.

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 2
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars

ProxyRequests Off

<Location /app1/services/App01>
    SSLVerifyClient require
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8307/app1/services/App01
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02
</Location>

<Location /app2/services/App02>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8307/app2/services/App02
</Location>
```